# Side effect of min() function

Tags: c++, c++11

I do not understand why the value of a[i] is being modified unintentionally? The line marked by the comment should only modify values of array p but not that of a. I have noticed that the values of array are being modified as a side effect. I cannot figure out why.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    unsigned int N, Q, K;
    unsigned int a[N], p[N][N];
    unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> counts_vector;
    cin >> N;
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        cin >> a[i];
        p[i][i] = a[i];
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            p[j][i] = min(p[j][i - 1], a[i]); // why is the value of a[i] getting modified?
        }
    }
    for (unsigned int k = 0; k < N; k++) {
        cout << "a: "<<a[k]<< endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the size of `a[N]` during execution time at the moment the code 'reaches' declaration?

Comment: min does not change the values passed to it. Are you sure you're populating it with the correct values in the first place.

Comment: Your code isn't valid. The variable `N` is uninitialized when execution reaches `unsigned int a[N], p[N][N];`. Get a better compiler with real warning/error messages.

Comment: How do you know it is 5? If you were computer, how would you know it?

Comment: @JesusRamos Yes, I am sure. I printed the values of a[i] before and after min invocation. They were different.

Comment: Thanks. It was stupid of me. Sorry for wasting your time. I am using g++ on OSX Mavericks. cc was giving too many errors related to clang :(

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't declare `unsigned int a[N], p[N][N];` before N is given a value!

change

```
unsigned int N, Q, K;
unsigned int a[N], p[N][N];
unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> counts_vector;
cin >> N;
```

to

```
unsigned int N, Q, K;
cin >> N;
unsigned int a[N], p[N][N];
unordered_map<unsigned int, unsigned int> counts_vector;
```

Comment: But not before C++14 (or accepting compiler extensions)

Comment: Or just use std::vector either way.